# How Can i do Only one checkbox selected at a time in given list in ngFor in angular 5?

Tags: checkbox, angular5, ngfor

I want to do only one checkbox selected at a time in ngFor in angular 5.
i have the following code below.

```
<div class="form-check" style="margin-top:0;">
   <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input"  id="res{{restaurant._id}}" (change)="selectRestaurant(restaurant,i)" [checked]="restaurant.checked" type="checkbox">
        <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

And in my component

```
selectRestaurant(restaurant: any, i: any) {
    if (restaurant) {
      restaurant.checked = !restaurant.checked;
    }
  }
```

So any possible solution for only one checkbox selected in given list?

Answer (score 1):

I saw many examples with loop using. But I`am think its bad idea when checkboxes are too many. I recommend to use another way.

Create variable to contain checkbox index.

```
public checkboxIndex = 0; //default value for checking
public checkboxModel = [];

ngOnInit() {
 for (let i = 0; i < checkboxCount.length; i++) {
 this.checkboxModel.push({ name: `${i}`, enabled: false });
}

public checkboxChange(index) {
    if (this.checkboxIndex !== index) {
      this.checkboxModel[this.checkboxIndex].enabled = false;
    }
    this.checkboxIndex = index;
  }

//HTML
<div *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxCount.length; let i = index">
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkboxModel[i].enabled" 
 name="checkboxModel[i].name"
                (change)="checkboxChange(i)"> </input>
</div>
```

It should help. Please correct me if I made some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the checkbox item with ngmodel to the specific instance in for loop.
This you can try with ReactiveForms. See one example https://stackblitz.com/angular/ayqnbvbkmpy